# Selenium webdriver chromedriver - is it possible to provide p12 certificate as ChromeOption (ssl-client-certificate-file)

Tags: selenium, ssl, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I am running automated UI tests using Chromedriver.

Tested site, requires authentication through p12 certificate. Once I open the page, certificate selection pop-up is displayed in Chrome.

I am aware of [AutoSelectCertificateForUrls](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls) feature. However, I want to use different certificates, depending on the particular test case.

Is it possible to use an option `--ssl-client-certificate-file`
mentioned in thread https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/18220/24148 with Chromedriver? I see that in the linked thread it is mentioned that it works only with PhantomJS, but maybe since the original post, it was implemented?